# How can I use the show method of my resource controller on a soft deleted model?

Tags: php, laravel, routes

So I have a resource controller called `ProjectController` and I added soft delete and use it as an archive.

```
Route::get('project/archive', 'ProjectController@trash')->name('project.archive');
Route::resource('project', 'ProjectController');
```

In this archive, I have a list of the projects.

```
public function trash()
{
    $projects = Project::onlyTrashed()->get();
    return view('projects.archive', compact('projects'));
}
```

Now I want to use the `show` method to view these projects.

In my `\App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider` I added:

```
Route::bind('project', function ($value) {
    return \App\Project::withTrashed()->find($value);
});
```

But this way, I am able to edit the project.

I tried to bind `project/show`, `project/{project}/show`, but that does not work.

**How can I use the `show` method of my resource controller on a trashed project?**

My complete ProjectController looks like:

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\ProjectRequest;
use App\Project;

class ProjectController extends Controller
{
 public function index()
 {
  $projects = Project::all();
  return view('project.index', compact('projects'));
 }

 public function create()
 {
  return view('project.create');
 }

 public function store(ProjectRequest $request)
 {
  Project::create($request->all());
  return redirect()->route('project.index');
 }

 public function show(Project $project)
 {
  return view('project.show', compact('project'));
 }

 public function edit(Project $project)
 {
  return view('project.edit', compact('project'));
 }

 public function update(ProjectRequest $request, Project $project)
 {
  $project->update($request->all());
  return redirect()->route('project.index');
 }

 public function destroy(Project $project)
 {
  $project->delete();
  return redirect()->route('project.archive');
 }

 public function trash()
 {
  $projects = Project::onlyTrashed()->get();
  return view('project.archive', compact('projects'));
 }
}
```

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: As I understand, by `binding` you get objects (Models in most cases) injected instead if just the int primary key you normally have. By this logic your `get` and `resource` definitions should have curly brackets. And your `trash` function should typehint a `Project` object

Comment: @ThomasMoors Automatic Injection is already provided by the Service Container.

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden But not the one corrosponding to the id from the url

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By adding a check in the `\App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider`.

```
Route::bind('project', function ($value) {
    if (Route::currentRouteName() === 'project.show') {
        return \App\Project::withTrashed()->find($value);
    }
    return \App\Project::find($value);
});
```

Hopefully this will help others.

Comment: This is what I needed! I needed this to show soft deleted items so they can be restored.

Answer (score 1):

I may be completely misunderstood the problem, but as far as I understood:

You can exclude some functions of a controller, such as;

```
Route::resource('photos', 'PhotoController')->only([
    'index', 'show'
]);

Route::resource('photos', 'PhotoController')->except([
    'create', 'store', 'update', 'destroy'
]);
```

More detailed information on https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/controllers#restful-partial-resource-routes

Additionally, if you want to implement a resource controller that uses only trashed projects -rather than a regular laravel model- as a resource you have to generate a new controller via something like

```
php artisan make:controller -r ProjectArchiveController
```

and customize the functions of it accordingly. For more options on make:controller command, you can use;

```
php artisan help make:controller
```

Hope this all helps.

New addition:

```
Route::get('project/{id}', 'ProjectController@trash')->name('project.archive');
Route::resource('project', 'ProjectController');
```

and declaration of the function trash,

```
public function trash(int $id)
```

Comment: I want to use the complete resource controller. I just want to be able to use the `show` method on trashed models (projects). I edited my question to be more clear.

Comment: I just got what you mean. And you found anotherway to solve but I found another solution for this so I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but you completely misunderstand the question. Also, trash does not need an id, this method collects the soft deleted models, and it is working just fine...

Comment: When you send a GET request to .../api/project/3 (3 is for example project id) you want to be able to get the project resource even if 3 is a soft deleted record. If that's not the case, just ignore the rest.

If trash method is being used, then just override the show method that takes id as a parameter and use a query like in the trash method. but instead of a collection use find($id) method to find your singular record. 

P.S: Default laravel resource controller does not have 'project/show' or 'project/x/show' kind of routes. What it includes as routes are written in the link I provided.

Answer (score 1):

I also posted on [laracasts.com](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/route-model-binding-with-soft-deleted-model?page=1&replyId=730238), where I partly borrowed from OP's answer.

I use this not for an archive of soft-deleted models, but for a restore route. But the problem is the same: **route model binding only works for non-trashed models**. I wanted a solution that:

- works on all models which use the `SoftDeletes` trait;
- only works on routes which are specifically meant for restoring soft-deleted models;
- only works on models which are actually soft-deleted;

Therefore, I utilized the `resolveRouteBinding()` method (originally in \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model), creating a more generic solution:

\App\Models\Traits\SoftDeletes:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Traits;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes as EloquentSoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

trait SoftDeletes {
    use EloquentSoftDeletes;

    /**
     * Retrieve the model for a bound value.
     * 
     * Modified from \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::resolveRouteBinding()
     *
     * @param mixed $value
     * @param string|null $field
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
     */
    public function resolveRouteBinding($value, $field = null) {
        $route_name_parts = explode(".", Route::currentRouteName());
        if (end($route_name_parts) === 'restore') {
            return $this->onlyTrashed()->where($field ?? $this->getRouteKeyName(), $value)->first();
        }
        return $this->where($field ?? $this->getRouteKeyName(), $value)->first();
    }
}
```

For OP's archive, just add another check on the route name in that `if`-statement.

On the model, I swap the Eloquent version of SoftDeletes for this one. Now I can just define a route as:

```
Route::patch(
    '/projects/{project}/restore',
    [ProjectController::class, 'restore']
)->name('projects.restore');
```

Thus only routes with a name ending in 'restore' will work on a trashed model, all other routes only work on non-trashed models.

### Note

With this, the `restore` routes exclusively work with trashed models. If you want them to work with non-trashed models as well (but why?), just replace the `onlyTrashed()` method with the `withTrashed()` method.

Comment: It would certainly be possible to make the route filter configurable, however, for my current project that is overkill. If this were a package, it would be great. And about the tests, are you referring to whether the `isSoftDeletableModel()` method still works? The output of `class_uses_recursive()` still also lists the Eloquent SoftDeletes trait, so that should work.

Comment: Note that this will not work for scoped routes where resolveChildRouteBinding on the parent model gets used instead: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#customizing-the-resolution-logic .

Answer (score 0):

You can add a withTrashed() method to the routes file.  From the laravel docs https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#implicit-soft-deleted-models

```
use App\Models\User;
 
Route::get('/users/{user}', function (User $user) {
   return $user->email;
})->withTrashed();
```