# Let show method of resource controller to show soft-deleted model using policy

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

## Steps to reproduce the issue I'm facing

1- Create the Item:

```bash
php artisan make:model Item --all
```

2- Create the resource in `web.php`:

```php
Route::resource('items', ItemController::class);
```

3- Then, in the `ItemController`'s constructor, link the `ItemPolicy`:

```php
public function __construct()
{
    $this->authorizeResource(Item::class);
}
```

4- Return true in all of the `ItemPolicy`'s methods (so you get authorized)

```php
public function view(User $user, Item $item)
{
    return true;
}
```

5- Add `SoftDeletes` trait in `Item` model:

```php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Item extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, SoftDeletes;
}
```

6- Add `SoftDeletes` in Item migration. Run it.

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('items', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->softDeletes();
    });
}
```

7- Write a dd in `show` method in `ItemController` to check out if you are actually entering inside the method:

```php
public function show(Item $item)
{
    dd('You are inside the show function');
}
```

8- Create a item in the db and go to GET `/items/1`. You should see the dd message.

```php
Route::get('/testCreate', function () {
    $item = Item::create();

    return redirect("/items/$item->id");
});
```

9- Delete the item. Now, in GET `/items/1`, the message doesn't appear anymore (instead, I get 404).

```php
Route::get('/testDelete', function () {
    $item = Item::firstOrFail();

    $item->delete();

    return redirect("/items/$item->id");
});
```

## The question

How to enter the show method in GET `/items/1` despite the model is soft-deleted?

**Notes**

- Make sure you are logged in
- I already checked out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52533236) but I'm not able to make it to work
- I also tried to change the show method in the controller to this way (`$id` instead of `Item $item`), but anyways I get 404. I'm not entering the method, policy is in the middle and doesn't let me in:

```php
public function show($id)
{
    dd($id);
    // dd($item);
}
```

Comment: You might need to pass in the ID instead of type hinting the item. Then you can do `$item =Item::withTrashed()->find($id);` in your show function.

Comment: @aynber But the issue is that if the model is trashed I can't enter to the show method in the controller, so I can't test what you are saying, I'll get 404 instead.

Comment: That's why you don't type hint the item. Use `public function show($id)` so that you can try to find the item yourself.

Comment: @aynber I already tried that too but I couldn't get into the show method anyways. I'll update the question adding this too.

Comment: @aynber, won't work since it's ``type hint``ed. It will return ``404``. To make it work, need to to make changes in the route service provider class.

Comment: @OMiShah I tried to do it this way, as you are saying, but I couldn't get to do it. Where should I put this code - https://stackoverflow.com/a/52535591/14569750 ? In what function?

Comment: @ericmp the file path is mentioned in the answer. In the boot function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was as that easy as adding the `withTrashed()` function at the end of the route resource route defined in `routes/web.php` file.

Before:

```php
Route::resource('items', ItemController::class);
```

After:

```php
Route::resource('items', ItemController::class)->withTrashed(['show']);
```

Related docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#implicit-soft-deleted-models) & [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#soft-deleted-models).

### Update

In an older project I had, despite of doing the explained above, I was getting this error:

```php
Method Illuminate\Routing\PendingResourceRegistration::withTrashed does not exist.
```

I solved it by updating the project's composer pagackes:

```
composer update
```

Now works fine.